# Python certification error - Certificate.command install not working/ permission denied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a developed segment of code that links back up to an existing website to cross ref multiple images - the issue I am encountering seems simple enough but now I feel that I went down a rabbit hole.

I should be able to run this code on my Mac but get the error:

> urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

Okay simple - I went to applications and tried to run the Install Certificates.command but then get the error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
>   13] Permission denied:
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

For both Python 3.7 & 3.8
Okay - I then tried pip(pip, pip3, pip3.7, & pip3.8) install on Certi and Certificates which all worked.

But I still get the error when running my code stating that my certification verification failed. I then did the something again this time with --user and still the same result.

Am I missing something to this - I feel very foolish trying to get this to work when it should be pretty simple.

Thanks

Comment: Solved - sudo with admin right - since this was a work comp hence the issue

Answer (score 0):

after taking some time away I went with sudo - and that was the correct move - should mention I was on work comp hence the issue - used admin rights and got cert verification.